# customization in Django admin site

Tags: django, django-models

How to change the placement / arrangement of the textbox or field?

this is the original arrangement

[image]

this is what i want to see organized textboxes:

[image]

this is my models.py

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):

   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True,blank=True)
   Username = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Password = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   lrn = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
   Firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Middle_Initial = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Parent_Users = models.ForeignKey(ParentsProfile, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,)
   Gender = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Birthday =  models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Place_Of_Birth = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Citizenship = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)

   Education_Levels= models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
   Religions = models.ForeignKey(Religion, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
   School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

my admin.py

```
@admin.register(StudentProfile)
class StudentProfile(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('lrn','Firstname', 'Middle_Initial', 'Lastname', 'Request')
    ordering = ('pk',)
    search_fields = ('lrn','Firstname','Lastname')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override styling/etc by using [custom js/css](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/media/#assets-as-a-static-definition):

```
@admin.register(StudentProfile)
class StudentProfile(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = ('js/admin/my_own_admin.js',)    
        css = {
            'all': ('css/admin/my_own_admin.css',)
        }
```

and [admin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Answer (score 0):

Basically django admin generate the html according to your models field and datatypes. it does not foucas on arrangement of the field and the ui look and fill if you want to change the arrangement or any ui thing you need to follow below steps

1. you need to change order in model
2. you can manipulate  the page behavior  by using external jquery lib and change the dom elements by targeting classes and ids